# Google Vision API authentication on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, heroku, vision-api

## What is a best, simple way to authenticate Vision API on heroku?

In development I just use:

```
@vision = Google::Cloud::Vision.new( project:  "instacult",
                                     keyfile:  "path/to/keyfile.json" )
```

Where keyfile is a json produced by google after creating service account (https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/common/auth).

But obviously I can't just upload the keyfile to github.

I tried saving whole json to Heroku's config vars and running:

```
Rails.env.production? ? ENV["GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS"] : path
```

But I got "is not a valid file" in heroku's logs. Seems logical since I'm not passing a file but an object. But how to get over it?

Cheers,
Kai

Answer (score 5):

**SOLVED:**

Turns out you can provide a json object in environment variable, but there is a naming convention.

> Here are the environment variables (in the order they are checked) for
>   credentials:
>
> 1. VISION_KEYFILE - Path to JSON file
> 2. GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEYFILE - Path to JSON file
> 3. VISION_KEYFILE_JSON - JSON contents
> 4. GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEYFILE_JSON - JSON contents

*source*: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-ruby/#/docs/google-cloud-vision/v0.23.0/guides/authentication

So I ended up with calling:

```
@vision = Google::Cloud::Vision.new( project:  "instacult")
```

Having set VISION_KEYFILE_JSON in my ~/.bashrc:

```
export VISION_KEYFILE_JSON='the_json_content'
```

and on heroku (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#limits).

Comment: I tried this method, I set up the VISION_KEYFILE_JSON in env and when I tried in my local it says ``` Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.``` But when I echo it shows the env