# How to Authenticate Google Vision/Cloud Using ENV Variable in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-cloud-platform, google-vision

My app is hosted on Heroku, so I'm trying to figure out how to use the JSON Google Cloud provides (to authenticate) as an environment variable, but so far I can't get authenticated.

I've searched Google and Stack Overflow and the best leads I found were:

[Google Vision API authentication on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42937145/google-vision-api-authentication-on-heroku)

[How to upload a json file with secret keys to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144135/how-to-upload-a-json-file-with-secret-keys-to-heroku)

Both say they were able to get it to work, but they don't provide code that I've been able to get work. Can someone please help me? I know it's probably something stupid.

I'm currently just trying to test the service in my product model leveraging this sample code from Google. Mine looks like this:

```
def self.google_vision_labels
  # Imports the Google Cloud client library
  require "google/cloud/vision"

  # Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
  project_id = "foo"

  # Instantiates a client
  vision = Google::Cloud::Vision.new project: project_id

  # The name of the image file to annotate
  file_name = "http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/27800000/FOOTBALL-god-sport-27863176-2272-1704.jpg"

  # Performs label detection on the image file
  labels = vision.image(file_name).labels

  puts "Labels:"
  labels.each do |label|
    puts label.description
  end
 end
```

I keep receiving this error,

`RuntimeError: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information`

Based on what I've read, I tried placing the JSON contents in secrets.yml (I'm using the Figaro gem) and then referring to it in a Google.yml file based on the answer in this SO question.

In `application.yml`, I put (I overwrote some contents in this post for security):

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: {
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "my_project",
  "private_key_id": "2662293c6fca2f0ba784dca1b900acf51c59ee73",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n #keycontents \n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "foo-labels@foo.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "100",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": 
  "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": 
  "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/get-product-labels%40foo.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

and in `config/google.yml`, I put:

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = ENV["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]
```

also, tried:

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: ENV["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]
```

I have also tried changing these variable names in both files instead of `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` with `GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEYFILE_JSON` and `VISION_KEYFILE_JSON` based on this Google page.

Can someone please, please help me understand what I'm doing wrong in referencing/creating the environmental variable with the JSON credentials? Thank you!

Comment: Im not 100% on this, Im not all that familiar with the figaro gem. I think its similar to the `dotenv` gem though. I know they can be used in a production environment (although I would recommend to use it only in dev/test environments) but if you are, it may be worth checking the Gemfile group the figaro gem has been added to matches the `RAILS_ENV` you are running the app on Heroku.  Also, I see from the figaro docs it says the deployment process for Heroku should be a case of running a command like `figaro heroku:set -e production`. I hope that helps.

Comment: Does your application work correctly if you launch it locally? Or do you have the same credential errors related to authentication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really annoying that Google decides to buck defacto credential standards by storing secrets via a file instead of a series of environment variables.

That said, my solution to this problem is to create a single .env variable `GOOGLE_API_CREDS`.

I paste the raw JSON blob into the `.env` then remove all newlines. Then in the application code I use `JSON.parse(ENV.fetch('GOOGLE_API_CREDS')` to convert the JSON blob into a real hash:

The `.env` file:

```
  GOOGLE_API_CREDS={"type": "service_account","project_id": "your_app_name", ... }
```

Then in the application code (Google OCR client as an example):

```
  Google::Cloud::Vision::ImageAnnotator.new(credentials: JSON.parse(ENV.fetch('GOOGLE_API_CREDS'))
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Building on Dylan's answer, I found that I needed to use an extra line to configure the credentials as follows:

```
Google::Cloud::Language.configure {|gcl| gcl.credentials = JSON.parse(ENV['GOOGLE_APP_CREDS'])}
```

because the `.new(credentials: ...)` method was not working for Google::Cloud::Language

had to look in the (sparse) ruby reference section of Google Cloud Language.

And yeah... storing secrets in a file is quite annoying, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Google Cloud Speech, using the "Getting Started" doc from Google.

The above answers helped a great deal, coupled with updating my Google Speech Gem to V1 (https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-cloud-speech-v1/latest/Google/Cloud/Speech/V1/Speech/Client.html)

Comment: Please add relevant sections of the answer here itself as links might change over time.

Answer (score 0):

I simply use a `StringIO` object so that Psych thinks that it's an actual file that I read:

```
google:
  service: GCS
  project: ''
  bucket: ''
  credentials: <%= StringIO.new(ENV['GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS']) %>
```